# Is this sentence right? (Among the first signs that...)

Tags: grammaticality

**Among the first signs that patriotic propaganda was losing
its effectiveness came in 2009, when Apple launched the iPhone in South Korea.**

(from  http://www.economist.com/news/business/21639579-locals-fed-up-paying-over-odds-are-shopping-abroad-won-over)

Is this a grammatically right sentence?  I can't find 'subject' and 'verb' of this sentence?

Shouldn't it be written like "One of the first signs that patriotic propaganda was losing its effectiveness came in 2009, when Apple launched the iPhone in South Korea"?

Comment: I agree with your rewrite. It took several readings of the original to notice the error, though, so I wouldn't be surprised that it slipped through the editor's office. Simply removing 'among' would also fix the sentence ('the first signs' - subject; 'came' - verb)

Comment: The sentences has no obvious subject, though the verb is *came*.

Comment: Coty is right.  Coty please make your comment an Answer.

Comment: You are entirely correct, Roo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative fix, keeping the intended phrasing:

"Among the first signs that patriotic propaganda was losing its effectiveness was Apple's 2009  launch of the iPhone in South Korea."